# C# + OLEDB insert varchar with special character?

Tags: c#, database, ole

I have a problem with this code, maybe you can give me a hand.
Im inserting file information as rows with name, size, ... they are all varchars
The problem is that the "name" has this ' tildes  in the namefile so when it tryies to parse the data it crashes.

the filename is : *Creedence Clearwater Revival - **Lookin'** Out My Back Door - 09.mp3*

**after "lookin" there is a '**

my command is:
oleDbInsertCommand1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `Dirs-Arcs` (`nombre`, `formato`, `tamaño`, `path`, `tags`) VALUES ('"+name+"', '"+formato+"', '"+tamaño+"', '"+path+"', '"+tags+"')";

this works fine with filenames without this ' characters, how can I parse this better????
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameters:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand ( "INSERT INTO dirs-arcs (nombre, formato, tamano, path, tags) VALUES (@name, @format, @tamano, @path, @tags)", connection);

cmd.Parameters.Add( "@name", OleDbType.VarChar ).Value = name;
// add all parameters
```

hth

Mario

Comment: Thanks Mario, that worked fine.
I saw an example like this one before, but until now I didn't understand it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use AccessDataSource with parameters. If you use parameters, you dont have any problem for special chars.